# How many first level charcters do you need to kill a tarrasque

Tags: dnd-5e

I was wondering if it is possible to kill a terrasque with only level 1 characters, and how many will you need?

Comment: Do you mean 'technically has a chance to win' or 'will likely win'?  A level-1 Aarakocra could fly around and shoot the tarrasque with an arrow (crits always hit), and as long as it stayed out of the tarrasque's reach it would be relatively safe.  It would take nearly 100 rounds to do it, but it's *possible*.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @Percival Frightful Presence is 120 ft, so you would more than likely be at disadvantage 100% of the time.

Comment: Seems to me this question hits square in the center of three kinds of question the tour says not to ask about: “Brainstorming requests (“give me some cool ideas”),
Questions that are primarily opinion-based (“what do you think about thing?”),
Questions with too many possible answers or that would require a novel-length answer”.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: @mxyzplk I see this as a question with a purely mathematical answer based on the statistics of the game

Comment: @illustro In a sense, but I'm not sure if that answer is what the OP really wants.

Answer (score 1):

Anything is possible, but this would be very ***very*** unlikely.

Unless the characters had some kind of magical item to reduce the damage or triple their AC, it probably wont matter how many level 1 characters you have, they will likely die.

At 676 hit points, and having an AC of 25, there almost no way the level 1s will hit it let alone do any damage. Even if they were flanking, the odds of hitting the attack roll are slim.

Not to mention that Frightful Presence will probably have everyone at disadvantage 100% of the time. So in order hit, you would need to roll 2 crits back to back (1 in 400 chance). The tarrasque also has advantage on all saving throws against magic.

Also, the Tarrasque can make 5 attacks per turn each that could one-shot a level 1 character easily. So every round of combat can effectively take out 5 characters.

Comment: Keeping in mind that the flanking rules are an optional variant in 5e.

Comment: (1/20)^2 = 1/400

Comment: @goodguy5 I had 400 in front of me, don't know why I put 200. Need more coffee. Thanks for the correction.